# How do I compare none types in python3 when converting python2 code

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparator

I'm stuck on a migration from python2 to python3 where a part of the script compares old values to new values. In python2 you could compare a "None" type but in python3, [you cannot](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons). Any suggestions on working around this?

Unfortunately, in this snippet below `reading` can be dirty data and contain "None" or None instead of a value.

Here is a snippet of the code (simplified):

```
# Meta data

do_meta_write = False
meta_data = all_meta_data[reading['device_key']]

# All time high
if value1 in value2 and reading1 in value2[value1]['all_time_high']:
        channel_meta = value2[value1]

        if reading['device'].model.channels[reading['channel_num']]['sensor_class'].newest_wins_tie:
            if channel_meta['all_time_high'][reading1] <= reading['reading_value']:
                do_meta_write = True
                channel_meta['all_time_high'] = ujson.decode(
                    reading['reading_json'])
        else:
            if channel_meta['all_time_high'][reading1] < reading['reading_value']:
                do_meta_write = True
                channel_meta['all_time_high'] = ujson.decode(
                    reading['reading_json'])
else:
    do_meta_write = True

    if not value2.get(value1):
        value2[value1] = {}

    meta_data['channel_data'][str(
        reading['channel_num'])]['all_time_high'] = ujson.decode(reading['reading_json'])
```

The error:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
channel_meta['all_time_high']['raw_values'][reading['reading_unit']] < reading['reading_value']_summarize)
```

Comment: Check if the values are not `None` before comparing.

Comment: Please provide a simple [mre] demonstrating the problem

Comment: Can you not leave it the way it is and wrap it in a try?

Answer (score 1):

You check if a value is `None` before using it in a context where `None` is not allowed. For example,

```
do_meta_write = False
if reading['device_key'] is not None:
    meta_data = all_meta_data[reading['device_key']]
    
    # All time high
    if value1 in value2 and reading1 in value2[value1]['all_time_high']:
        channel_meta = value2[value1]

    ...
```

Comment: This isn't the key being compared with `<=`

Comment: I didn't feel like wading through the whole script to find the comparison. The point stands: if a value can't be used if it is `None`, you have to check for it first, regardless of *why* it can't be used.

Comment: But the issue is only with the change between Python 2.x and 3.x. 2.x didn't allow `None` to be used as a dictionary key, so this code couldn't be where the compatibility issue is.

Comment: That's beside the point. I'm only saying that if `None` is not a valid value, in whatever context, check if the value is `None` before using it. (And you could always use `None` as a dictionary key; nothing changed between 2 and 3.) (Or at least, it's legal in 2.7.16 when I test it.)

Comment: And I'm just saying that the question is about a very specific problem. It used to be possible to use `if a < b:` where `a` or `b` was `None`, now it isn't, and he wants to know how to deal with that in his code that depended on the old behavior.

Comment: The same way: `if a is not None and a < b:` Check that the value is not `None` before using it in a context where `None` will produce an error.

Comment: Exactly Barmar!

Answer (score 1):

Test for `None` before comparing. E.g. change

```
if channel_meta['all_time_high'][reading1] <= reading['reading_value']:
```

to

```
if reading['reading_value'] is not None \
    and channel_meta['all_time_high'][reading1] is not None \
    and channel_meta['all_time_high'][reading1] <= reading['reading_value']:
```

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, thank you @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

A few options come to mind:

1. Simply drop all records with `None` in this field.
2. Replace all `None`s with a sentinel value that will never exist in your input data.  Optionally convert those back to `None` after comparisons are done.
3. Explicitly check for `None` at comparison time, and handle that case differently if necessary.